# UI angular modal controller $scope values handling mistake

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using angular UI modal, in the template of my modal I have 2 inputs and a button, this are using th ng-model attribute,  ok, I have a controller set for the modal, which works, it does everything but getting the values of the inputs even when I set a value in the controller for the input it changes it, but when I try to get the value from the template I got an undefined response, I make this plunker and kinda insert my modal and made a controller for it one button sets a predefined value in the input and the other one tries to get it , I hope somebody could help me, thx

http://plnkr.co/edit/7NCbo28DbDc8vkxjE2gx?p=preview

Comment: you plunker is not available.

Answer (score 2):

The modal window has its own scope. What you'll want to do is take your model and make it an object. So take `bootusername` and name it something like `bootusername.text`

You can then initialize `bootusername` in the instance controller and set the model like so:

```
var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance)
{
  $scope.bootusername = {}; //initialize the object

  $scope.check1 = function()
  {
    $scope.bootusername.text = 56; //set the object here or just type in input
  };

  $scope.check2 = function()
  {
    console.log($scope.bootusername.text);
  };

  $scope.ok = function()
  {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function()
  {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
};
```